# Yamabe's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is PDE Evans, 2nd edition: Chapter 9, Exericse 8(a).

> 8. (a) Assume $n \ge 3$. Find a constant $c$ such that $$u(x) := (1+|x|^2)^{\frac{2-n}2}$$ solves *Yamabe's equation* $$-\Delta u = cu^{\frac{n+2}{n-2}} \quad \text{in }\mathbb{R}^n.$$ Note the appearance of the critical exponent $\frac{n+2}{n-2}$.

My work so far:

Given $u(x):= (1+|x|^2)^{\frac{2-n}2}$, we find that $$u^{\frac{n+2}{n-2}}=(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2}.$$

Also, I differentiate $u(x)$ to find $$u_{x_i}=(2-n)(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac n2} x_i.$$ I differentiate again to find \begin{align}
u_{x_i x_i} &= (2-n)\left[-n(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2} x_i^2 + (1+x^2)^{-\frac n2}\right] \\
&= (2-n)[-nx_i^2 +(1+x^2)](1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2}.
\end{align}

Therefore, the negative Laplacian is
\begin{align}
-\Delta u = -\sum_{i=1}^n u_{x_i x_i}  
&= (n-2)[-n|x|^2 +n(1+x^2)](1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2} \\
&= (n-2)n(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2}
\end{align}

Putting these altogether, Yamabe's PDE $-\Delta u=cu^{\frac{n+2}{n-2}}$ becomes $$(n-2)n(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2}=c(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2}.$$

This would mean that $$c=n(n-2).$$

I had fixed my work acordingly (see my revision history), so this is actually the answer. I do [have a follow-up question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305631/yamabes-equation-continuation-question), though.

Comment: If $|x|^2= \sum x_i^2$, then $\frac{d|x|^2}{dx_i}=2x_i$. I think you are having an extra $|x|$ when differentiating $u(x)$.

Comment: @SrinivasK If I may ask, how do my derivatives look now?

Comment: We are missing another $x_i$ in $u_{x_ix_i}$.

Comment: Your follow-up question gives a “page not found“.

Comment: @Keba apparently I deleted that question quite some time ago, but I  undeleted the question just now.

Comment: @Cookie: Thanks for your fast answer. I was hoping the other question covers part (b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have $$u_{x_i x_i} = (2-n)\left[-n(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2} x_i^2 + (1+|x|^2)^{-\frac n2}\right].$$
That is, not $x_i$, but $x_i^2$ in the squred bracket. Therefore, we have
$$-\Delta u=-\sum_{i=1}^nu_{x_i x_i} = -(2-n)\left[-n(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2} |x|^2 + n(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac n2}\right]=n(n-2)(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2}$$
where the second equality follows from $|x|^2=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$.
As you have calculated, $u^{\frac{n+2}{n-2}}=(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2}$. We have
$$-\Delta u=n(n-2)u^{\frac{n+2}{n-2}}.$$

Comment: Okay, now based on this expression of $u_{x_i x_i}$, the PDE would now imply that $$c=(n-2)[-n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 +(1+x^2)](1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{n+2}2}.$$ Is $c$ a constant because all the $x$ (and $x_i$) terms are squared?

Comment: Yes, see edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think While calculating $u_{x_ix_i}$ we have missed the summation for $(1+x^2)$.If we take that into account, the constant would be $n(n-2)$.